# limit total number of characters in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

The string can be a number or a set of numbers, or two groups of numbers separated with "-", but total count of all characters mustn't be more than 6.

Example of valid strings

```
5
55-33
4444-1
1-4444
666666
```

Example of invalid strings

```
-3
6666-
5555-6666
```

My regex

```
/^\d+(-?\d+)?$/
```

But this regex interprets `5555-6666` as a valid string, though its length is more than 6 characters.

I tried following

```
/^(\d+(-?\d+)?){1,6}$/
```

but, than I recognized that it interpret enclosed charset as one group, which it expects from 1 to 6.

So how to control total number of chars just with a regexp and requirements described above?

Comment: You have two rules here: one or two numbers joined by a dash and at most 6 characters in total. The first one can be tested using a regex (but also by other means). The second one is easier and it doesn't involve anything but the [`.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) property of your string. Don't try to achieve everything using a regex. Regex is a powerful tool but it cannot solve all the problems in the world.

Comment: @axiac yes, I agree. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Method 1 :-***

Easiest thing you can do it is testing the length before regex (i will prefer using this method which checks length and then use regex)

```
str.length < 7 && /^\d+(-?\d+)?$/.test(str)
```

***Method 2 :-***

You can use positive lookahead

```
^(?=.{0,6}$)\d+(-?\d+)?$
```

[image]

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/5e5CAP/2/)

Comment: What's the usefulness of the lookahead? The length of the string has already been tested using `str.length < 7`.

Comment: @axiac lookahead method is standalone method, which is an alternative if you don't want to go for length method, okay let me separate it as option1 and option2 to avoid further confusion

Comment: The lookahead is genius. I love it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a positive lookahead pattern to ensure that there can be a maximum of 6 characters:

```
^(?=.{1,6}$)\d+(?:-\d+)?$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/kAxuZp/1

Or you can a negative lookahead pattern to ensure that the string does not start with a dash, and another negative lookahead pattern to ensure that the string does not contain two dashes:

```
^(?!-)(?!.*-.*-)[\d-]{0,5}\d$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/kAxuZp/3

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use your current regex pattern and also check the length of the input with dash removed:

```js
var input = "4444-1";
if (/^\d+(-?\d+)?$/.test(input) && input.replace("-", "").length <= 6) {
    console.log("MATCH");
}
else {
    console.log("NO MATCH");
}
```

Note that checking the length of the input is only really meaningful *after* the dash has been removed, because it is only then that we can assert the total number of actual digits.

Comment: `but total count of all characters mustn't be more than 6.` IMO you don't need to replace `-` before checking length of string,